# Database synchronisation with WSO2 SI

Tags: wso2, wso2-streaming-integrator

does any one have an idea if Stream Integrator can be used in achieving mysql to mysql synchronisation ¿ where a change on Database A is reflected in B and vice versa.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [siddi-io-cdc](https://github.com/siddhi-io/siddhi-io-cdc) xtension to capture the changes to MySQL. However you have to write the updates to the B MySQL server in Siddhi.

This blog has more info. [https://dzone.com/articles/change-data-capturing-with-wso2-streaming-integrat#:~:text=For%20CDC%2C%20WSO2%20Streaming%20Integrator,SQL%20Server%2C%20H2%20and%20Oracle](https://dzone.com/articles/change-data-capturing-with-wso2-streaming-integrat#:%7E:text=For%20CDC%2C%20WSO2%20Streaming%20Integrator,SQL%20Server%2C%20H2%20and%20Oracle).